# Novice to DB - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm pretty new to Oracle and Database.

I'm trying to write a stored procedure with cursors. How do I write a select statement inside the cursor loop, and how do I loop through the result set that I get from the select inside that cursor loop?

For example:

```
    Open Curs1;
    Exit When Curs1%NotFound;
    Loop
       Select column1,column2  from table -- Returns multiple records. How to loop through this record set and perform CRUD operations.
    End loop;
    Close Curs1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a FOR-loop cursor - they are faster and simpler than the open/fetch/close syntax.

```
begin
    for results1 in
    (
        select ...
    ) loop
        --Do something here
        for results2 in
        (
            select ...
            where some_table.some_column = results1.some_column
        ) loop
            --Do something here
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Although this literally answers the question, you generally do not want to have loops inside loops like this.  If possible, it would be better to combine the two SQL statements with a join and then loop through the results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `CURSOR` and `FETCH` the records in the loop.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR  curs1
IS
  SELECT column1,
         column2
  FROM   yourtable;

  v_column1 yourtable.column1%TYPE;
  v_column2 yourtable.column2%TYPE;
BEGIN
 OPEN curs1;
  LOOP

    FETCH curs1
    INTO  v_column1,
          v_column2;
  EXIT
  WHEN curs1%NOTFOUND;

    INSERT INTO yourtable2(col1)VALUES( '000'||v_column1  ); 
    -- A sample DML operation.

    --Do other operations on individual records here.
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE curs1; 
END;
```

Comment: You are missing 'open curs1', and should fetch first, and then use exit when curs1%notfound.

Comment: Thanks! It was Editing mistake and  untested ...:)

Answer (score 0):

*Try to use the following example that fetches rows one at a time from the cursor variable emp_cv into the user-defined record emp_rec:*

```
declare
   TYPE YourType IS ref cursor return YourTable%rowtype;
   tab_cv  YourType;
   tab_rec YourTable%rowtype;
begin
   loop
      fetch tab_cv into emp_rec;
      exit when tab_cv%notfound;
      ...
   end loop;
end;
```

*The BULK COLLECT clause lets you fetch entire columns from the result set, or the entire result set at once. The following example, retrieves columns from a cursor into a collection:*

```
declare
   type NameList IS table of emp.ename%type;
   names NameList;
   cursor c1 is select ename from emp where job = 'CLERK';
begin
   open c1;
   fetch c1 bulk collect into names;
   ...
   close c1;
end;
```

*The following example uses the LIMIT clause. With each iteration of the loop, the FETCH statement fetches 100 rows (or less) into index-by table acct_ids. The previous values are overwritten.*

```
declare
   type NumList is table of number index by binary_integer;
   cursor c1 is select acct_id from accounts;
   acct_ids NumList;
   rows natural := 100;  -- set limit
begin
   open c1;
   loop
      /* The following statement fetches 100 rows (or less). */
      fetch c1 bulk collect into acct_ids limit rows;
      exit when c1%notfound;
      ...
   end loop;
   close c1;
end;
```